# Heroku Deploy With Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, devise

I am attempting to deploy my app using heroku with Ruby on Rails. It's a simple task app using devise for my user registrations. I believe the problem is the devise registrations controller as my logs seem to tell me.

```
> 2016-05-25T17:45:50.379667+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
> 2016-05-25T17:45:50.379741+00:00 app[web.1]:                ^
> 2016-05-25T17:45:50.379749+00:00 app[web.1]:  from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require' 2016-05-25T17:45:50.379740+00:00 app[web.1]: class  MyDevise:RegistrationsController < Dev...
> 2016-05-25T17:45:50.379724+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
> 2016-05-25T17:45:50.379717+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.5 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:22282
> 2016-05-25T17:45:50.379738+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': /app/app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:1:
> syntax error, unexpected tSYMBEG, expecting '<' or ';' or '\n'
> (SyntaxError) 2016-05-25T17:45:50.379722+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run
> `rails server -h` for more startup options
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I will post any other files needed, I did not modify the registrations controller so as of now I don't have access to that.
Thank you!

```
class MyDevise:RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
def new
    render :new
end

def edit
    render :edit
end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class definition is missing a semicolon.

`class MyDevise:RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController` should be `class MyDevise::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController`

Comment: Any luck, @chrishorton?

Comment: Fixes the syntax error, although one still prevails that says uninitialized my devise constant

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with Devise, you are simply getting a syntax error in `/app/app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:1` Could you show us the first lines of that file?

It should look something like this:

```
class MyDevise::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
# ...
```

Also, you are deploying WEBrick to Heroku, I recommend you follow their [guidelines](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4) and deploy with Puma instead. This is not the problem you are experiencing, but following the guidelines of the platform will help you out in the long run.

**EDIT**: You and me where both missing a semicolon after `MyDevise`. I added it so we don't spread the error and to make it easier for other readers.

Comment: Okay, updated the question to include the registrations controller that I have currently.

Comment: Please choose @pdoherty926 answer below. He has it right! I'm updating my answer to help other's see it.